# Storing in memory database Using ORMLite for Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, ormlite, sqliteopenhelper

I am developing an app for android. I have a Web Service which i will be doing the database queries and storing in. In the beginning of the app i want to load certain data from the web service via REST calls and store it in a local database, preferably ORM. I have found ORMLite and like how it can be used but i was wondering how i could make the database be stored in memory so that the data gets wiped when the app quits.

When i use

```
public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, null, null, DATABASE_VERSION,R.raw.ormlite_config);
}
```

as stated in the documentation it throws the a runtimeException. Any advice on how to accomplish this or another way to go about it will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that the Android database APIs support an in memory database -- even though SQLite does support it.  I also don't think it is going to be useful to load something like H2 onto Android just to get a in-memory DB.

I'd suggest that you persist the data and then just wipe the database every time your application starts.  Yes it will be doing unnecessary IO but shouldn't be too bad.  ORMlite supports a [`TableUtils.clearTable()` method](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/table/TableUtils.html#createTable%28com.j256.ormlite.support.ConnectionSource,%20java.lang.Class%29).

Also, you might consider *not* using an ORM and just store the objects in collections if the whole point is not to persist them.